# Julia: fields of structs passed by value

Tags: julia

In the following piece of Julia code, st.a and b are the same array, so when I delete an element from st.a, then this element is also deleted from b. Is it possible that a new array "*.a" is generated, every time a create an object * of Mystruct?

```
struct Mystruct
     a::Array{Int64,1}
     Mystruct(a::Array{Int64,1}) = new(a)
end

b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
st = Mystruct(b)
deleteat!(st.a,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that:

```
struct Mystruct
     a::Array{Int64,1}
     Mystruct(a::Array{Int64,1}) = new(copy(a))
end
```

will do the job you want.

Comment: No need for `deepcopy`, use `copy`.